# Use of C++ templates with dynamic binding class

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, dynamic-binding

In the past I have used both templates and dynamic binding in C++, however recently I attempted to use them together and found that it was impossible to compile.

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
     std::map<MyClass, unsigned int> mymap;
```

Where MyClass happens to be a class utilizing dynamic memory binding. After a few hours of searching I am given the impression that this causes implications which I still can't resolve, so I  was hoping for some guidance on the issue and how it can be resolved.

My final goal is to be able to do something like this:

```
std::vector<MyClass> MyClassPool;
//fill the vector with MyClass objects...
for(usigned int i=0 ; i<MyClassPool.size() ; i++)
{
    mymap[ MyClassPool[i] ] = i;
}
```

I have tried using pointers in various ways but it's not working and I fail to see what can be done.

I get the following errors with the above:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h: In member function `bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = Instance]':

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:338:   instantiated from `_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = Instance, _Tp = float, _Compare = std::less<Instance>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Instance, float> >]'

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h:227: error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic memory binding"? Anyway, your code looks correct. You need to give us the definition of `MyClass`.

Comment: didn't you mean `vector` instead of `Vector`? You are using the standard builtin `std :: vector`, aren't you?

Comment: And what does "it's not working" mean? You have to give us better information. Does it compile? What error message do you get?

Comment: strangely I get compile errors directing me to the library. I will edit the original question to include them. ANd yes I am using the standard std::vector

Answer (score 2):

That compile error means you have no `operator <` defined for `Instance`. `map` needs to be able to sort keys and needs this function. If you'd rather not define `operator <`, you need to provide a comparison function as a third template parameter for `map`, i.e. `std::map<Instance, float, compare_instances>`.

... Come to think of it, you're sure you want `Instance` as the key and `float` as the data, and not the other way around? I.e. you're searching in the map for an `Instance` to get a `float` in return?

Comment: Yes that is correct, Instance classes need to be used as keys.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide `operator<` for `MyClass`. It is required by `std::map`. You have two options: provide a comparator as the third template argument to `map` OR implement the operator in `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with "dynamic binding" (which is not what is meant here anyway).  Your class needs to have an order to be put into a map.  It needs operator<.

Comment: In one attempt I noticed an error mentioning the need for an overloaded operator< . Could you elaborate?

Comment: Just write `bool MyClass::operator<(MyClass const& other){/*however you want to compare your classes*/}` as a method of your MyClass class.  The "however" part is up to you, but it should be something that obeys the basic order requirements of `operator<`.